# tcpdump filter expression breaks via adb

Tags: shell, quoting, adb

I installed tcpdump on my Android tablet and am running commands from a root adb shell. I'm working from [the tcpdump man page examples](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html), specifically this one:

> To print all IPv4 HTTP packets to and from port 80, i.e. print only packets that contain data, not, for example, SYN and FIN packets and ACK-only packets.

```
tcpdump 'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'
```

If I execute the above command on my desktop (Ubuntu), it runs fine. If I try and execute it on my Android device, like this:

```
adb shell tcpdump 'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'
```

I get this error:

```
/system/bin/sh: can't create 2)) != 0): Read-only file system
/system/bin/sh: here document missing
tcpdump: syntax error
```

And the following command runs fine on the Android device:

```
tcpdump 'tcp port 80'
```

It seems like the filter expression isn't being parsed properly, or something, but I'll be honest, I'm not sure how exactly it works, so I'm not sure where to start with troubleshooting. Any ideas as to what's going wrong or how to fix it?

Comment: There is something in the filter that you must have write access to do.

Comment: I'm assuming the `>>` in the filter is a shift, and it's being interpreted as an output redirect and trying to create a file called "2))!=0)". The filter should just be filtering packets, not writing anything.

Comment: If you need to learn tcpdump rules, you have to read `man pcap-filter`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quotes cause the command `adb` to be passed three arguments:

1. `shell`
2. `tcpdump`
3. `tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)`

It presumably then tries to run the command

```
tcpdump tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)
```

*without* the quotes (as the shell on the machine on which you typed the command removed the quotes) on the Android machine.

You can probably do

```
adb shell tcpdump "'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'"
```

which means that the `adb` command will be passed

1. `shell`
2. `tcpdump`
3. `'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'`

so that it will try to run the command

```
tcpdump 'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'
```

on the Android machine.

The same problem would exist with, for example, `ssh`; the command

```
ssh localhost tcpdump 'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'
```

gets the errors

```
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `tcpdump tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure where exactly the command wasn't being interpreted correctly, but there's no longer a problem if instead of this:

```
adb shell tcpdump 'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'
```

I open the shell first, and then execute tcpdump:

```
adb shell
tcpdump 'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'
```